# Questionst about Vulkan VkSubpassDependency members

Tags: vulkan

I'm studying Vulkan RenderPasses, for hobby.

I have the following descriptions for members of VkSubpassDependency struct.
The verbiage is a combination of language from sources(books, spec, internet), and
my own word-smithing. The descriptions might be wrong because of my messing with them.

```
// .srcSubpass: 
//      The subpass index from which "producing" operations should be finished before the second set of "consuming" operations executes.
//      If there are no dependencies on previous subpasses(eg: first subpass), use VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL.
// .srcStageMask:
//      A bitmask of the pipeline stages which produce the data read by the "consuming" commands.
// .srcAccessMask:
//      The types of memory operations that occurred during the "producing" commands.
// ----------
// .dstSubpass:
//      The index of the first subpass whose operations depend the output of this subpass; or VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL, if 
//      there are no destination subpasses dependencies.
// .dstStageMask:
//      A bitmask of the pipeline stages which depend on the data generated by the "producing" commands.
// .dstAccessMask:
//      The types of memory operations that will be performed in "consuming" commands.
```

### I have some questions

Lets say that a RenderPass has 3 subpasses -- S1, S2, S3 -- which are "logically" executed in sequence, but which may be executed out of order by the GPU.

- 1. **srcSubpass:**
- 1.1. Is it possible for there to be a scenario in which S3 does not depend on either S1 nor S2? Or do subsequent subpasses *always* depend on some previous pass?
- 1.2. If 1.1 is true, then `srcSubpass` would be `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL`, correct?
- 1.3. Or, does `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` only ever apply to S1?

---

- **2. dstSubpass:**
- 2.1. Is this simply *always* the index of the next logical subpass (ie: S1->S2)? Or is it possible for it to be S1->S3?
- 2.2. Similar to question 1.1, is it possible for S3 not to depend on S2, and thus this value would be `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` for S2?

---

- **3. srcStageMask:**
- 3.1. Is it the case that the earlier the pipeline stage is, the less the dependency between the 2 sets of operations would be?
  That is, a `srcStageMask` of `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_INPUT_BIT` would have a smaller dependency time than `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT`.
- 3.2. If 3.1 is true, then this means that the ideal pipeline stage would be `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT`, correct?

---

- **4. dstStageMask:**
- 4.1. For a smaller dependency time between 2 sets of operations, the farther down the pipeline, the better?
- 4.2. If 4.1 is true, then `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT` would be the ideal stage, for minimum dependency. Yeah?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.1 Anything that is not impossible\invalid is by definition possible. Might make sense to render to two independent color attachments using the same vertex buffer. Might save on binning, which need only be done once.

1.2 Not necessarily. For example a subpass might have no color attachments and instead output via Storage Images. Therefore it needs no `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` dependecy, explict nor implicit.

1.3 No it applies to whichever subpass uses given attachment first, as that one executes the LoadOp for that attachment.

2.1 Yes, it is a dependency DAG, so it might have S1→S3, S2→S3 (and no S1→S2).

2.2 It might be `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL`. Note you can have more dependencies; one can be `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` and other may have another subpass. One attachment in S2 might be finished and have early StoreOp here, and therefore `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` would be appropriate for it.

3.1 Yes, the more logically-earlier stage is used in `srcStageMask`, the restriction imposed by such dependency is lesser or equal.

3.2 Yes, that would be a no-op dependency. Coincidentally this is how the implicit subpass dependency is specified.

4.1 Yea, same logic. The more logically-later stage is used in `dstStageMask, the restriction imposed by such dependency is lesser or equal.

4.2 That is the no-op dependency. And coincidentally this is how the implicit subpass dependency is specified.

Comment: 1.2: Is this because the subpass would not perform a loadOp? I assume that implies that the driver wouldn't even consider the `srcSubpass` field. I also assume that the determination that subpass is not performing a loadOp is based on srcAccessMask.

Comment: 1.3: You're using "uses" as defined by the Spec, Chapter 7? Basically, (related to your 1.2), if you're writing to a Storage Image, then that's not an instance of "using" the attachment, as defined by Chapter 7, and therefore the value of srcSubpass is immaterial?

Comment: 2.2: "Note you can have more dependencies;" You mean, in different subpasses, not within the same subpass, correct?

Comment: ad 1.2: Simply, when you have nothing to synchronize, then there would be no dependency needed; `EXTERNAL` or otherwise. When there is no attachment, then there is no load op. That means there is not even an implicit dependency. Though that is a theoretical distinction, not really useful for anything. Perhaps I should have asked where you are going with your questions...

Comment: ad 1.3 Yes, "using" in the specification sense. An attachment is loaded in the first subpass that it is used in. And an attachement is stored in the last subpass it is used in. LoadOp and StoreOp is usually the main thing to consider when syncing attachment resources to the outside of renderpass. So if a second subpass uses a specific attachemnt first, then it should likely have an `EXTERNAL` dependency (unless otherwisely synced).

Comment: ad 2.2 Yes, with the same subpass. You can have both `EXTERNAL`→2, and 1→2 dependencies. Only restrictions are both `srcSubpass` and `dstSubpass` are not allowed to be `EXTERNAL`. And `srcSubpass` must be less or equal to `dstSubpass` (to make the dependency graph acyclic). Plus `srcSubpass == dstSubpass` has special meaning. Otherwise everything else is allowed.

Comment: "Perhaps I should have asked where you are going with your questions..." -- I'm just in the learning phase of Vulkan. I want to make sure to understand the synchronization stuff well. It's one of the things that makes me the most nervious about the API. I want to be confident that I'm using sync operations correctly and efficiently.